# How to avoid large padding between nav dropdown menu and rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar, dropdown

So what I need to do might be simple but I have no clue after long hours of research.

I want to make my page shifting down when I am hovering on my dropdown menu. (if this is not possible) I would like to avoid a big padding between my HEADER and the rest of my page, SECTION>TITLE...

Is there any chance to do so without using any jQuery or JavaScript?

Many thanks for your time and patience.

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title>Emblem Collectible Books</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="all">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
        <script src="shifter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header id="pageheader" role="banner">
                <div id="commonlink">
                    <nav id="commonlinkbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div id="logo">
                    <div class="innerlogo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="mainnav">
                    <div id="navwrapper">
                        <nav id="primary" role="navigation">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="navbar"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="books.html" class="drop">Books</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">20th Century Books</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="19thcentury.html">19th Century Books</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">18th Century Books</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Rare Books</a></li>
                                    </ul></li><li>
                                <a href="delivery.html">Delivery</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">About</a></li><li>
                                <a href="#">Books as an Investment</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main id="mainc" role="main">
                <section id="introduction" role="introduction">
                    <div id="title">
                        <h1>Welcome to <span class="titleintro">Emblem</span>, Rare collectible Books</h1>
                    </div>**
```

---

Here is the css

```
/* Embed the fonts before anything else */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'parisr';
    src:url("../fonts/parisr.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/parisr.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/parisr.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../fonts/parisr.svg#parisr") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Page Styling */

#page {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pageheader {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 455px;
}




/* Common links styling */ 

#commonlink{
    float: right;
    padding-left: 4%;
    width: 30%;
}

/* Commmon link bar */

#commonlinkbar{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#commonlinkbar li a{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #236841;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

#commonlinkbar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
} 

#commonlink ul li :hover:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #236841;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#commonlink ul li a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #236841;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}


#commonlink ul li a:hover{
    color: #309c64;
}



/* Logo */

#logo{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.innerlogo{
    width: 55%;
    padding: 0% 20%;
}

.innerlogo img{
    max-width: 100%;
}



/* Main navigation bar styling */

#mainnav{
    width: 100%; 
}

#navwrapper{                             /* Navigation bar position */
    width: 66%;                    
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    padding: 0% 14%; 
}

#mainnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#mainnav ul li{                            /* Navigation bar border design */
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #236841;
    border-left-color: #3cc37d;
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-left-style: inset;
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0px 0;
}

#mainnav li a{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family: 'parisr', Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#mainnav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    animation: bounce 1s;   
}

#mainnav ul li a,visited{
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



#mainnav ul li a:hover{                        /* Navigation bar bounce effect */
    color: #236841;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right-color: #236841;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    animation: bounce 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutUp;
    animation-name: bounceOutUp;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  40%, 45% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }

  100% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
  }

  @keyframes bounceOutUp {
  20% {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  40%, 45% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
  }

  100% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -2000px, 0);
  }
}


#mainnav ul li:hover ul{                   /* Navigation bar dropdown menu design */
    display: inline-block;
    color: #236841;
}

#mainnav ul ul{
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#mainnav ul  ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
}

#mainnav ul ul li a,visited{
    color: #fff;
}

#mainnav ul ul li:hover{              /* Navigation bar dropdown menu bounce effect */
    color: #236841;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceOutRight;
    animation-name: bounceOutRight;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes bounceOutRight {
  20% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(2000px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(2000px, 0, 0);
  }
  }

  @keyframes bounceOutRight {
  20% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(2000px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(2000px, 0, 0);
  }
}



/* breadcrumbs */

#breadcrumbs{
    width: auto;
    padding: 1%;
}

#breadcrumbs a{
    color: #000;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Main content style */

#mainc{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}



/* Section Introduction style */

#introduction{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
}



/* Title page style */

#title{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0% 10%;
}
```

Comment: please try to break down your code to the bear minimum. There is a lot going on here and that makes it harder to understand where and with what you are struggling with.

Comment: Thanks, I have reduced the css.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

make a div the size you need 
add to css

```
myDiv {
    display: none;
}

a:hover + myDiv {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or adjust the declared height of the header div....

```
#pageheader {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 455px; /* <-- either remove this line or change it to something correct */
}
```

Based on the pieces you've supplied, it seems that height is the bulk of the header. If you want it smaller, you need to change or remove that declaration.

Removing it would allow the header div to be whatever automatic height is needed to display the contents within the div which are *not* set as floats.

Comment: Hi Scott, when i remove the height yes of course it nest everything up, but this doesn"t allow me to se the content of my dropdown menu when hovering it.

Comment: declaring the height, (which of course is not good here) allow me to see the dropdown action. This is what I am trying to avoid to add to the code.

Comment: You need to rework the drop down CSS then. You shouldn't need the height for drop downs to work.

Comment: Hi Scott, ok i have removed the "height" of the PAGEHEADER, then set the MAINNAV to absolute, and then a pdding-top to the rest of my page. It sort everything but i wanted to now  if this was possible to make the rest of the page shifting down when I am hovering on the navbar without using JavaScript?